# How to make android emulator use inside camera?

Tags: android, ip, android-camera, android-camera-intent, ip-camera

I was using LDmultiplayer emulator and see that they got a "QR CODE" feature
that automatically opened a second screen and took whatever was ahead, so I just place it on a pic that had the QR and it would detect. Want to do something similar but use the camera only instead of "Qr". Any idea?

TLDR: The emulator need to take a picture of a picture that is inside it

Answer (score 1):

Click on the More button to open the Extended controls window. On it click on the Camera tab. There you will see two options to add images, one on the wall and one on the table.

[image: Add images]

Add your image/images and they will be displayed in the emulator.

[image: Images added]

Comment: Thank u so much Sid